# How to change Concrete class name in Argument for a derived class method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am trying to have a  APIController which provide functions just as same as that of laravel's Default route controller as follows

```
//Routes.php
Route::resource('keys', 'KeysController'); 
Route::resource('SomeOther', 'SomeOtherController'); 





abstract class APIController extends Controller {

    public function store() 
    {
        return $this->respondNotSupported();
    }


}

class KeysController extends APIController {


    public function store(KeysRequest $request)
    {
        $input = Request::all();
        $newkey =   Key::create($input);
        return $newkey->id;
    }
}


class SomeOtherController extends APIController {


    public function store(SomeOtherRequest $request)
    {
        $input = Request::all();
        $newkey =   SomeOtherModel::create($input);
        return $newkey->id;
    }
}
```

So I want to swap the  classes , just like as laravel can accept any classes in FormRequest for the store method

But I gets the following Error ,

```
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\KeysController::store() should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\APIController::store()
```

which is fine because the signature doesn't match. So How  can I achieve this? and where can I find how laravel is able to accept any kind of class for that argument.

Comment: That's not possible. Laravel doesn't do this either. There is no abstract controller with actual actions (`store()` etc) in the framework because it is not possible. What exactly do you want to achieve with this? just the `respondNotSupported` thing?

Comment: SomeOtherRequest and KeysRequest are derived from Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest  class  If I  do not have APIController class in between  Things works fine.  As of now I am just having 'respondNotSupported' .  So laravel does it somehow. How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't do that. (And Laravel doesn't do that either)

---

What you can do to handle missing methods in your abstract controller is use the magic method `__call()`. If implemented, this method will be called by PHP if a method that doesn't exist is called on your controller.

This is what Laravel does in `Illuminate\Routing\Controller`:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist.");
}
```

That means you can do pretty much the same with `respondNotSupported`:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    return $this->respondNotSupported();
}
```

And obviously you could use `$method` (which is just the name of the called method) to do some more complex filtering:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if($method == 'store'){
        return $this->respondStoreNotSupported();
    }
    return $this->respondNotSupported();
}
```

Comment: This Surely does answers my  Question, Thanks.  Can you please point me to right direction on how does a method in controller is able to accept Request Or any Other class derived from Request of FormRequest then?

Comment: Well since the method signature is only defined in the controller itself, it can be whatever the controller wants. If you're asking how the objects actually get passed, that's the magic of dependency injection through Laravels IoC container. Basically Laravel analyses the parameters you typehint and resolves those dependencies...

Comment: Okay , perfect ! everything makes sense. 
I guess I was trying to achieve the same magic on my controller myself somehow.